# Training and Testing accuracy not increasing for a CNN followed by a RNN for signature verification

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently working on online signature verification. The dataset has a variable shape of (x, 7) where x is the number of points a person used to sign their signature. I have the following model:

```
    model = Sequential()
    #CNN
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(None, 7)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='sigmoid'))

    #RNN
    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0))
    model.add(LSTM(8))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

    opt = Adam(lr=0.0001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    print(model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=2, batch_size=50))

    score, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test,y_test, verbose=2)
    print(score, accuracy)
```

I know it may not be the best model but this is the first time I'm building a neural network. I have to use a CNN and RNN as it is required for my honours project. At the moment, I achieve 0.5142 as the highest training accuracy and 0.54 testing accuracy. I have tried increasing the number of epochs, changing the activation function, add more layers, moving the layers around, changing the learning rate and changing the optimizer.

Please share some advice on changing my model or dataset. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CNN-RNN, some promising things to try:

- **Conv1D layers**: `activation='relu'`, `kernel_initializer='he_normal'`
- **LSTM layer**: `activation='tanh'`, and `recurrent_dropout=.1, .2, .3`
- **Optimizer**: `Nadam`, `lr=2e-4` (Nadam may significantly outperform all other optimizers for RNNs)
- **batch_size**: lower it. Unless you have 200+ batches in total, set `batch_size=32`; lower batch size better exploits the Stochastic mechanism of the optimizer and can improve generalization
- **Dropout**: right after second `Conv1D`, with a rate `.1, .2` - or, after first `Conv1D`, with a rate `.25, .3`, but *only* if you use SqueezeExcite (see below), else `MaxPooling` won't work as well
- [SqueezeExcite](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01507): shown to enhance all CNN performance across a large variety of tasks; Keras implementation you can use below
- **BatchNormalization**: while your model isn't large, it's still deep, and may benefit from one BN layer right after second `Conv1D`
- **L2 weight decay**: on *first* `Conv1D`, to prevent it from memorizing the input; try `1e-5, 1e-4`, e.g. `kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-4) # from keras.regularizers import l2`
- **Preprocessing**: make sure all data is normalized (or standardized if time-series), and batches are shuffled each epoch

```
def SqueezeExcite(_input):
    filters = _input._keras_shape[-1]

    se = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(_input)
    se = Reshape((1, filters))(se)
    se = Dense(filters//16,activation='relu',   
               kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)
    se = Dense(filters,    activation='sigmoid',
               kernel_initializer='he_normal', use_bias=False)(se)

    return multiply([_input, se])
```

```
# Example usage
x = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
x = SqueezeExcite(x) # place after EACH Conv1D
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have implemented all of the above (except the SqueezeExcite as I was having a problem understanding what to do). But I still have the same results.

Comment: @AbigailLeahSingh What is your full train dataset size, and full validation dataset size?

Comment: I'm using the SVC dataset. It's not a very large dataset; there are only 1200 signatures hence I have only split it into training and testing sets. I have split them 60-40, 70-30 and 75-25 for results purposes.

Comment: @AbigailLeahSingh 1200 signatures, so each 'signature' has the shape `(1,7)`, correct? If so, your dataset is far too small for deep learning - and you're better off using 'shallow' methods such as Support Vector Machines (or getting a larger dataset). -- If you insist, cut down the model size significantly so you're left with no more than ~10,000 parameters. Also, I'd recommend the [Model API](https://keras.io/models/model/) over Sequential, as it's more flexible and intuitive - for which the `SqueezeExcite` above is written.

Comment: Each signature has a shape of (n, 7) as each person takes n points for each signature. That is why I have used a variable input (None, 7). I do have another dataset that I can use: SigComp2009 and each signature has the shape (n, 5). This has a training set of 1906 signatures and a testing set of 1552 signatures. If I were to use this dataset, would it be more effective?

Comment: @AbigailLeahSingh All depends on the _total # of datapoints_, which would be determined by the average value of `n`. If `n` is comparable for both, SigComp2009 is more promising. Also, _never_ work without a validation set - if necessary, sacrifice the test set; it's trivially easy for Deep NNs to overfit. To reliably estimate test accuracy in the end, use [K-fold CV](https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199812/discussion-between-abigail-leah-singh-and-overlordgolddragon).