# LSTM time series forcasting - starting with low loss, and accuracy does not change

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to predict network traffic based on past values. I built an LSTM network, and tried several parameters, however I always end up with the same very low accuracy (0.108).

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
print(len(train), len(test))

def create_dataset(dataset, window_size = 1):
    data_X, data_Y = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - window_size - 1):
        a = dataset[i:(i + window_size), 0]
        data_X.append(a)
        data_Y.append(dataset[i + window_size, 0])
    return(np.array(data_X), np.array(data_Y))

window_size = 1
train_X, train_Y = create_dataset(train, window_size)
test_X, test_Y = create_dataset(test, window_size)
print("Original training data shape:")
print(train_X.shape)

# Reshape the input data into appropriate form for Keras.
train_X = np.reshape(train_X, (train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X = np.reshape(test_X, (test_X.shape[0], 1, test_X.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape = (1, window_size)))
model.add(Dense(1))
opt = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = opt, metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

As you can see my loss starts from quite a low value, and my accuracy constant over time. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance. :)

You can find the loss and accuracy graph here:
[loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otcsc.png)
[accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsNEE.png)

Comment: Can you please mention what is the shape of your X_train?

Comment: Training: (13942, 1, 1)

Comment: See updated answer; your model probably works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `(13942, 1, 1)` is your entire dataset, it's far too small for deep learning; you're better off using 'shallow' methods, e.g. Support Vector Machines (SVM). Alternatively, consider my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58044089/10133797).

**EDIT**: I just noticed that you use the `accuracy` metric; accuracy for regression is undefined - I'm surprised an error wasn't thrown. If it uses `prediction==true` to compute accuracy, you're lucky your accuracy isn't 0. Based on the loss, your model appears to be actually doing quite well; to double-check, plot `predictions` vs `true` and compare. (In general, `mse < .3` is good, and `mse < .1` is excellent)

Comment: @anon An LSTM layer is deep by design, via backpropagation through time. It's a _different_ kind of 'deep', but shares the property of requiring a lot of data to be effective. Granted, a cell size of 8 is very small, and it _might_ work, but I wouldn't bet on it

Comment: I don't particularly agree on that, deep learning came a lot after the design of lstm, gru. So, saying that an LSTM layer is deep by design doesn't make much sense. Deep learning also is not something only reserved for neural networks, you can have deep svm, deep forests. So, kindly provide reference from a rigorous source which everyone will appreciate.

Comment: Your comment on MSE is also not exactly correct. You should know how, acc is implemented in keras. It should never throw errors, and it actually gives a rounded match, which is not absurd completely, but it's better to avoid in regression settings.

Comment: @anon RNNs recursively pass information across hidden states, and backpropagate gradients across each state to update the weights (and hence require _more data_ to learn per given `hidden_dim`, `timesteps`). So yes, they are, by design, deep along the recurrent dimension. Whether or not Keras accuracy throws an error, it's a meaningless usage in regression context and must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to randomly shuffle the data.
2. LSTMs are best used when sequential data is used. Try to replace LSTM with the Dense layer. Or change your inputs. You need to pass a sequence of past values to the LSTM so that it can predict the next value. So, (1,1) is not a sequence, LSTM is not useful here.
   Metric accuracy is useless in this context, try mean absolute error or something.