# Training loss goes up and down during an epoch in a regression model. Also, model performance on a test set is relatively poor (~40% average error)

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a regression model for apartment prices prediction using Keras. During fitting training loss goes up and down a lot with little to no improvement. What is the problem here? I've tried dropout, regularization, making the network deeper, shallower, wider, narrower, increasing and decreasing learning rate, increasing and decreasing validation set, increasing and decreasing batch size.

```
import pandas as pd
from keras import Sequential
from keras import regularizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.constraints import NonNeg
from keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop, SGD
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='Лист1')
df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=1).reset_index(drop=True)

train_data = df.loc[0:145008, 'id_poligon_level_3':'kitchen_area']
y_label = df.loc[0:145008, 'price_usd':'price_usd']

pred_test = df.loc[145008:, 'id_poligon_level_3':'kitchen_area']
pred_y_label = df.loc[145008:, 'price_usd':'price_usd']

#maxPrice = np.max(df.loc[0:146008, 'price_1sq_meter_usd':'price_1sq_meter_usd'].values)

scale_train_X = StandardScaler()
train_data = scale_train_X.fit_transform(train_data.values)
scale_train_Y = StandardScaler()
y_label = scale_train_Y.fit_transform(y_label.values)
#y_label /= maxPrice
pred_test = scale_train_X.fit_transform(pred_test.values)
#pred_y_label /= maxPrice
pred_y_label = scale_train_Y.transform(pred_y_label.values)

'''
data = xl.load_workbook(filename='data.xlsx')
sheet = data['Лист1']'''

#maxPrice = np.max([val[0].value for val in sheet['H2:H146009']])

'''
def get_training_data():

    train_data = []
    for j in range(2, 146010):
        for val in sheet['B'+str(j)+':H'+str(j)]:
            train_set = []
            train_set.append([cell.value for cell in val])
            train_data.append(train_set)
    try:
        assert train_data is not None
        print('Getting training data process finished successfully')
        return train_data
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error")


def get_y_label():

    train_set = [val[0].value for val in sheet['L2:L146010']]
    train_set /= maxPrice

    try:
        assert train_set is not None
        print('Getting y label data process finished successfully')
        return train_set
    except AssertionError:
        print(AssertionError)


train_data = get_training_data()

train_data = np.asarray(train_data)
train_data = np.reshape(train_data, [1, train_data.shape[0], 7])
train_data = train_data[0]

for i in range(0, train_data.shape[0]):
    summ = 0
    for j in str(int(train_data[i][0])):
        summ += int(j)
    train_data[i][0] = summ

y_label = train_data.T[6]
y_label = np.reshape(y_label, [1, y_label.shape[0]])

test_data = train_data[87000:]
train_data = train_data[:87000]

test_data = test_data.T[:6]
train_data = train_data.T[:6]

y_label_test = y_label[0][87000:]
y_label = y_label[0][:87000]

#y_label_test /= maxPrice
#y_label /= maxPrice
y_label = np.reshape(y_label, [1, y_label.shape[0]])
y_label_test = np.reshape(y_label_test, [1, y_label_test.shape[0]])

'''
'''
def get_test_data():

    test_data = []
    for j in range(100001, 146010):
        for val in sheet['B'+str(j)+':I'+str(j)]:
            train_set = []
            train_set.append([cell.value for cell in val])
            test_data.append(train_set)

    try:
        assert test_data is not None
        print('Getting test data process finished successfully')
        return test_data
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error")


def get_test_label():

    test_set = [val[0].value for val in sheet['L100001:L146009']]
    test_set /= maxPrice

    try:
        assert test_set is not None
        print('Getting y label test data process finished successfully')
        return test_set
    except AssertionError:
        print(AssertionError)


test_data = get_test_data()
y_label_test = get_test_label()

test_data = np.asarray(test_data)
test_data = np.reshape(test_data, [1, test_data.shape[0], 8])
test_data = test_data[0]

y_label_test = np.asarray(y_label_test)
y_label_test = np.reshape(y_label_test, [1, y_label_test.shape[0]])

assert test_data.shape[0] == y_label_test.shape[1]


sc_train_X = StandardScaler().fit(train_data)
sc_train_Y = StandardScaler().fit(y_label)
sc_test_X = StandardScaler().fit(test_data)
sc_test_Y = StandardScaler().fit(y_label_test)

train_data = sc_train_X.transform(train_data)
test_data = sc_test_X.transform(test_data)
y_label_test = sc_test_Y.transform(y_label_test)
y_label = sc_train_Y.transform(y_label)

'''
def build_regression():

    model = Sequential([
        Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(6,), kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='Zeros'),
        #BatchNormalization(),
        #Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='Zeros'),
        #BatchNormalization(),
        #Dropout(0.1),
        Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='random_normal', bias_initializer='Zeros'),
        ])

    opt = Adam(lr=1e-4, decay=1e-3 / 200) #Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.98)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
    return model

estimator = build_regression()#KerasRegressor(build_regression, batch_size=16, epochs=100, validation_split=0.3)

estimator.fit(x=train_data, y=y_label, batch_size=16, epochs=100, validation_split=0.3, shuffle=False, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=5)])

#estimator.fit(x=train_data, y=y_label, batch_size=96, epochs=250, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)

predict = estimator.predict(pred_test)
predict = scale_train_Y.inverse_transform(predict)
pred_y_label = scale_train_Y.inverse_transform(pred_y_label)

diff = predict - pred_y_label
percDiff = (diff / pred_y_label) * 100
absPercDiff = np.abs(percDiff)
mean_perc = np.mean(absPercDiff)
std_perc = np.std(absPercDiff)

print('Mean error percentage: {} \nStandard error percentage: {}'.format(mean_perc, std_perc))

'''
model_json = estimator.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
regressor.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
'''
```

Output:

```
Train on 101506 samples, validate on 43503 samples
Epoch 1/100
2019-09-29 12:41:56.065057: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2

    16/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 36:14 - loss: 0.1636
   896/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 44s - loss: 0.6881  
  1520/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 29s - loss: 0.5158
  2192/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 22s - loss: 0.6153
  3088/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 17s - loss: 0.8603
  4016/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 14s - loss: 0.7997
  4944/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 12s - loss: 0.9174
  5840/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 1.0359
  6688/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.9711
  7472/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.9186
  8336/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 0.8943 
  9232/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.8843
 10128/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.8377
 11056/101506 [==>...........................] - ETA: 8s - loss: 0.7994
 11984/101506 [==>...........................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 0.7640
 12912/101506 [==>...........................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 0.7327
 13808/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 0.7647
 14736/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 7s - loss: 0.7474
 15664/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.7393
 16576/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.7204
 17504/101506 [====>.........................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.6941
 18448/101506 [====>.........................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.6858
 19392/101506 [====>.........................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 0.6624
 20320/101506 [=====>........................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6431
 21248/101506 [=====>........................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6349
 22192/101506 [=====>........................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6385
 23120/101506 [=====>........................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6409
 24064/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6310
 25008/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6638
 25904/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6495
 26752/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6451
 27616/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6402
 28448/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.6285
 29360/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6177
 30208/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6194
 31056/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6105
 31936/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6181
 32800/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.6073
 33632/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5983
 34496/101506 [=========>....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5917
 35360/101506 [=========>....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5834
 36208/101506 [=========>....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5833
 37104/101506 [=========>....................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5940
 37952/101506 [==========>...................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5937
 38848/101506 [==========>...................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5950
 39744/101506 [==========>...................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.5859
 40656/101506 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5809
 41568/101506 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5721
 42464/101506 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5673
 43376/101506 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5745
 44272/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5830
 45168/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5803
 46016/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5893
 46992/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5844
 47920/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5794
 48816/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5725
 49712/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5688
 50656/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5686
 51568/101506 [==============>...............] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5622
 52496/101506 [==============>...............] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5594
 53392/101506 [==============>...............] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.5529
 54320/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5494
 55248/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5438
 56176/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5374
 57104/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5347
 58032/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5325
 58960/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5272
 59904/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5218
 60848/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5171
 61776/101506 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5180
 62704/101506 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5206
 63648/101506 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5192
 64528/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5205
 65392/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5179
 66304/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5147
 67216/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5106
 68096/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.5122
 68960/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5087
 69824/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5048
 70704/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5066
 71584/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5114
 72480/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5068
 73344/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5029
 74224/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5022
 75104/101506 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5036
 75984/101506 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5017
 76816/101506 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4990
 77600/101506 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4959
 78416/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5045
 79248/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5044
 80080/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5015
 80912/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.5000
 81728/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4969
 82576/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4954
 83424/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4917
 84288/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.4908
 85200/101506 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4895
 86128/101506 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4898
 87040/101506 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4914
 87936/101506 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5128
 88848/101506 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5126
 89744/101506 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5132
 90624/101506 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5102
 91536/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5073
 92448/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5036
 93344/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5030
 94240/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5010
 95104/101506 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4980
 95984/101506 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4956
 96896/101506 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4931
 97776/101506 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4928
 98656/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4901
 99552/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4872
100448/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4875
101328/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4850
101506/101506 [==============================] - 7s 69us/step - loss: 0.4844 - val_loss: 0.3809
Epoch 2/100

    16/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 18s - loss: 0.0778
   928/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.1726 
  1840/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.1622
  2688/101506 [..............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.2834
  3568/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.2775
  4448/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.2740
  5360/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3466
  6288/101506 [>.............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3877
  7232/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3647
  8144/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3463
  9072/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3689
  9984/101506 [=>............................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3552
 10928/101506 [==>...........................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.3515
 11856/101506 [==>...........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3333
 12784/101506 [==>...........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3246
 13696/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3461
 14640/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3441
 15568/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3416
 16464/101506 [===>..........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3337
 17392/101506 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3213
 18288/101506 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3251
 19200/101506 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3165
 20096/101506 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3106
 21008/101506 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3036
 21920/101506 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3175
 22816/101506 [=====>........................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3159
 23712/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3225
 24608/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3269
 25520/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3477
 26400/101506 [======>.......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3490
 27328/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3496
 28272/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3469
 29200/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 0.3442
 30112/101506 [=======>......................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3502
 31008/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3480
 31904/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3549
 32832/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3537
 33792/101506 [========>.....................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3507
 34704/101506 [=========>....................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3510
 35616/101506 [=========>....................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3505
 36528/101506 [=========>....................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3498
 37488/101506 [==========>...................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3664
 38416/101506 [==========>...................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3635
 39344/101506 [==========>...................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3681
 40272/101506 [==========>...................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3648
 41232/101506 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3614
 42192/101506 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3578
 43152/101506 [===========>..................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3639
 44080/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3728
 45008/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3785
 45968/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3899
 46864/101506 [============>.................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.3891
 47776/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3859
 48672/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3831
 49568/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3818
 50448/101506 [=============>................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3825
 51376/101506 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3814
 52288/101506 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3807
 53200/101506 [==============>...............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3764
 54144/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3758
 55072/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3733
 55968/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3696
 56864/101506 [===============>..............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3698
 57824/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3687
 58768/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3659
 59696/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3630
 60624/101506 [================>.............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3606
 61552/101506 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3633
 62464/101506 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3683
 63376/101506 [=================>............] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3688
 64320/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.3670
 65248/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3695
 66176/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3686
 67088/101506 [==================>...........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3656
 67936/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3676
 68816/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3651
 69712/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3639
 70624/101506 [===================>..........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3671
 71536/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3728
 72448/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3699
 73344/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3676
 74256/101506 [====================>.........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3686
 75184/101506 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3707
 76112/101506 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3698
 77040/101506 [=====================>........] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3684
 77968/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3680
 78960/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3762
 79872/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3766
 80816/101506 [======================>.......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3755
 81728/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3736
 82672/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.3733
 83552/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3708
 84528/101506 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3706
 85456/101506 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3699
 86336/101506 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3712
 87264/101506 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3740
 88192/101506 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3960
 89072/101506 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3997
 89984/101506 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3976
 90928/101506 [=========================>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3951
 91840/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3932
 92768/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3909
 93664/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3916
 94576/101506 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3896
 95488/101506 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3882
 96416/101506 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3860
 97328/101506 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3867
 98240/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3851
 99152/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3825
100048/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3818
100960/101506 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3817
101506/101506 [==============================] - 6s 64us/step - loss: 0.3808 - val_loss: 0.3671
```

After 100 epochs the loss stays around 0.36

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just hit the local minima that is not intended. The things that you can also try is:

- Change the optimizer.
- Increase the learning rate in a way that you just overshoot the local minimums with a **well-designed decay** (You might need high decay) to keep track on better loss value.
- Change the activation functions.

OR

A possible thing that you have to suspect is the **data itself**. It might be so noisy to be fitted in. You have to check whether you have a noisy data or not by simply check with `matplotlib` in this case. However do not forget that, as I've understand from your code, it may be computationally expensive since you have like 200k points.

If it is so hard to check with the plotting, you can eliminate the noisy data with some filters that may differ with the situation itself.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead and try cheking for noisy data!

Comment: Would you, please, suggest some filters to eliminate noisy data? Because I've found some, like moving averages, but I cannot find the implementation for it neither in Keras nor in sklearn or should I create it myself?

Comment: you can check `scipy.signal` for some filters in [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html). If no filters fit for you, you can keep researching or create it yourself.

Comment: So I've tried the medfilt in scipy signal, and it did smooth out the data, but now values predicted by a model stay pretty much the same(28000.  30000.  33000.  33000.  39500.  43000.  44900.  55000.  57000. 57000.  57000.  57000.  57000.  57000.  57000.  57000.  57000.  45000. - labeled values) (51176.516 50982.773 49764.08  52163.695 53525.676 50610.38  51251.547
 50278.383 51542.2   49634.09  51027.613 53747.734 51347.758 49710.777 - predicted values) and mean squared error explodes on a test set

Answer (score 0):

Your results appear fine, if not great for the data you have; `val_loss` is very close to `loss`, which is basically ideal. In absolute terms, `.36` validation loss is pretty good - `<.25` would be excellent - but the main indicator is that it's close to your train loss, so *data* is the most likely limiting factor.

The confusion may be from the title: "`~40% average error": **loss != error**. For regression, "accuracy" is not defined (you can only measure the 'closeness' of predictions vs. labels; if you measured accuracy as with classification, it'd always be close to zero as you'd have to match labels, which are float32 real-numbers, *exactly*). If you'd like to get an even better idea of how your model is doing, *plot* predictions vs. labels.

Comment: Yeah, about ~40% accuracy thing. Its just the piece of code I took from this guide https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/01/21/regression-with-keras/, its just an approximation of model performance I guess

Comment: @Kojimba It uses the mean absolute percentage difference - the _lower_, the better. It can work fine if all values are within an order of magnitude - else the metric becomes unstable to outliers. As a truer metric for model performance, use MSE - for better intuition, plot labels vs. predictions

Comment: so I've plotted labels vs predictions and judging by the plot its doing fine, but not great. Also, the mean squared error is extremely big. Is that alright?

Comment: @Kojimba Not alright - what's the mse? Also, able to share the plot? Can try [this](https://postimages.org/)

Comment: mse is mean squared error. Here is the plot https://postimg.cc/QByWQQqW

Comment: @Kojimba I meant what's the value of the mse you're getting? Also, this isn't the best plot for comparison - try plotting the difference of labels vs. values, or plotting each as a line on the same graph

Comment: Oh, so the mse on the test set is 9148150033.7319. I'll make a plot and get you the link asap

Comment: @Kojimba Yeah, that's basically impossible unless your model has `NaN` weights or your `mse` computation is faulty. Double-check all your code/data - the one in your question is a good comparison since it works as intended.

Comment: Yeah, so the mse was so huge because I inversed standardization before calculating the mse. Still, the mse is around 0.38. Is there anything I can do to make it even less?

Comment: @Kojimba It's already excellent since it's so close to your train loss, and again data can be the limiting factor. Nonetheless you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043002/training-and-testing-accuracy-not-increasing-for-a-cnn-followed-by-a-rnn-for-sig/58044089#58044089), though generally SO's for code-specific problems, not ML advice - latter's better suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).