# expected time_distributed_38_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (13974, 100, 6, 5)

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm, keras-layer

train size :  13974 
test size  :   3494
train shape :  (13974, 101, 6, 5) 
test shape :   (3494, 101, 6, 5)
train input shape :  (13974, 100, 6, 5) 
train output shape :   (13974, 1, 6, 5) 
test input shape :   (3494, 100, 6, 5) 
test output shape :   (3494, 1, 6, 5)

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'), 
input_shape=(100, 6, 5,1)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Activation('relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(512)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(35, name="first_dense_flow" )))

model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, name="lstm_layer_flow"));    
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(101), name=" time_distr_dense_one_ flow "))  
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="global_avg_flow"))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_input,train_output,epochs=50,batch_size=60)
```

I got ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_38_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (13974, 100, 6, 5)

I need to predict (1,6,5) from (100,6,5) where 100 is timestamp.

Please correct any changes needed in the model

Answer (score 0):

See rewritten snippet:

```py
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'), input_shape=(100, 6, 5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(512)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(35, name="first_dense_flow" )))

model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, name="lstm_layer_flow"));    
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(101), name=" time_distr_dense_one_ flow "))  
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="global_avg_flow"))
```

- Drop the `1` in `input_shape`; `input_shape` is `batch_shape` without the batch dimension - so you'd have `batch_shape = (60, 100, 6, 5)` (since `batch_size=60`)
- Your data shape is `(101, 6, 5)` but your `input_shape` is `(100, 6, 5)` - this may not always work; either set `input_shape=(101, 6, 5)` or slice data before feeding to model (e.g. `x[:, :100, :, :]`)
- `Conv2D` doesn't need `TimeDistributed`, as your input is 3D (minus batch dim)
- `Activation`, `MaxPooling2D`, and `Dropout` automatically scale with their input dimension, so `TimeDistributed` is redundant
- `Flatten` will eliminate `timesteps`-`channels` relationship, and it may not be a sound addition - but if you were to use it anyway, you'll need to rid of `TimeDistributed` for the two `Dense` after, then `Reshape` before feeding to `LSTM`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am building the model for spatio  temporal time series for 6 locations 5 features and so the data is 13974 sequence 100 time stamps for 6 locations and 5 variables (features) . Is the model suitable for this?

Comment: @RagulKesavanS Your model will work with it, yes - as to whether it's among the 'standard' configurations for the problem, I wouldn't know - though it'd also be outside the scope of this question. What I'd recommend is keeping your `Dense` units comparable to Conv/LSTM's - so `512` and `101` are an overkill, and should be made e.g. `64, 32` (can do `128` for the very first `Dense`). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043002/training-and-testing-accuracy-not-increasing-for-a-cnn-followed-by-a-rnn-for-sig/58044089#58044089) for other tips.

Comment: Implementing the above snipit gives me an syntax error. Please provide me with the right syntax.

Comment: @RagulKesavanS Fixed - if it was hard to spot, consider switching to another IDE (e.g. Spyder)